# WPF Editable Focus Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf `ComboBox` with the ‘is editable’ flag set to true.  I have some code which gives it focus.
The focus event just makes the control selected.  The behavior I need is to place the cursor in the editable portion so the user can just start typing.
I’m quite new to WPF.  I’ve also search for similar questions but none of the solutions I tried worked, most seem to center on finding the template for editable textbox, but this always returned null.

Answer (score 2):

You could get a reference to the `TextBox` and set its `CaretIndex`:

```
TextBox textBox = comboBox1.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", comboBox1) as TextBox;
textBox.Focus();
textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text.Length;
```

Comment: what does the cmb bit mean ?

Comment: Should be name of the ComboBox, i.e. "comboBox1".

Comment: Then the ComboBox has probably not been loaded yet. Where you run the code?

Comment: does it matter that it sits within a stack panel?  Also on load that stack panel is Collapsed

Comment: Yes, you need to expand it from the ComboBox to get created. But try to handle the Loaded event for the ComboBox and put the code in there.

Comment: I tried putting the code into the laoded event but it made no difference

Comment: Post some code that can be used to reproduce your issue then. It works fine for me but of course you must have a reference to the ComboBox you want to focus...

Comment: So I just removed the combobox from the stack panel and it works fine. So its that which is the problem.
Actually outside the stack panel, it needs no extra code and the focus method works just fine.

Comment: not really, I still have the same problem, I  cannot access the textbox template when the combo box is inside the stack panel

Comment: That's *another* issue. You didn't mention anything about a ComboBox in your original question.

Comment: ah, problem solved, changed the stack panel from collapsed to hidden and now it works, using just the default focus() code.

Answer (score 0):

Set the visibility of the parent stack panel from Collapsed to Hidden and now it works fine.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer your original question...mine does.